# What is the correct way to import a type library in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, com, visual-studio-2013, midl, tlbimp

**Background**

Our build uses ant and a custom task to build Visual Studio projects/solutions as well as some Java projects. There structure is basically a large tree and artifacts from the projects are typically copied upwards to a common build directory.

This was previously a complete mess and I've greatly simplified the ant scripts and now I'm most of the way through the Visual Studio projects/solutions. These projects are extremely old and have been upgraded through every version of Visual Studio up to 2013. Part the changes I have done was to use as many of the default project properties and macros as possible. Most of these used to be hard coded.

Although I have modified the projects to use the $(Configuration) macro to separate the artifacts from different configurations these still get copied to a common location for other dependent projects in other solutions. So to avoid confusion and actually make sure our debug builds link to all the debug libraries (which wasn't happening previously) I have been adding suffixes to the Target Name. E.g. The Target Name of a Debug Unicode build will be $(ProjectName)DU.

**Problem**

This has been great so far but now I'm not sure how to complete these changes for one of our COM libraries. This library has an IDL file and the MIDL compiler generates a TLB file. Maybe this isn't a good way to do it but for now I wanted the TLB file to also have a different suffix depending on the build. The problem is, when I change the Type Library property for the MIDL configuration then this breaks the Compile-time directives in the RC file. I figured it might be possible to use #ifdefs in the TEXTINCLUDE block depending on whether _UNICODE or _DEBUG are set (provided I do it via the Resource Includes dialog so I don't break the RC file). It also means that there are other importlib attributes that will also need #ifdef checks.

At the moment it kinda works without renaming the TLB files but that's only because they are currently only being used within this solution.

Has anyone ever done anything like this or know a better solution?

**Update**

I guess what I really need to know here is what is the best way to use types from one COM DLL in another one? Should I even be using importlib? The MSDN documentation says that in most cases you should be using the import instead. I tried this but broke a whole bunch of stuff.

Comment: Sure there's a better solution, give each configuration its own build directory.  Sounds to me you are heading for endless trouble with configurations overwriting each others files, that .tlb should be just the tip of the iceberg.

Comment: Each configuration (within VS) does have its own build directory so the build configurations within a solution don't overwrite each other. It's the ant build that is copying the artifacts from other solutions that has to be a bit more careful. It used to frequently overwrite the artifacts since they had the same name and a common location. Perhaps changing the ant build to keep them separate is a better idea but harder to tell at a glance which library is which.